# How can I make two different colored borders around an image?

Tags: image, css, background

I want to be able to make a 2px white border with an 8px tan border around an image that automatically changes with the size of the image.

```
article.post .wp-caption img, article.page .wp-caption img {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 2px solid white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

If you want to look at the site here is the link:
http://www.metnews.org/news/aurora-remembers-holmes-victims/

Comment: 2 options: `img{padding:2px; background:#fff; border:8px solid (w/e color);` or `img{border:2px solid white; outline: 8px solid (color);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
border: 2px solid white;
outline: 8px solid yellow;
```

The `outline` property acts like an outer border.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use padding to get the effect of a second border. The part of changing size according to the image, I think you should explain a little better what you are trying to achieve.

```
padding: 2px;
background: white;
border: 8px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or box-shadow - you can have as many borders as you want.  Poor 'old IE8 and less won't get the pretty styles :(.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/KmnUB/2/

```
img {
    /* Make sure to add vendor prefixes */
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px white, 0 0 0px 10px tan;
}
```